# Pearson correlation and significance of the correlation

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 6 lines and 14 columns. I calculate the Pearson correlation through:

```
#read data
data1 <- read.csv("test.csv")

#calculate correlation 
pearson_coef <- cor(data1[sapply(data1, is.numeric)])
```

And I get the correct correlation coefficients. Now I would like to get the significance level of the correlation. So I used:

```
significance <- cor.test(data1)
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in cor.test.default(data1) : 
  argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

I don't understand what is the problem. Could you help me?

Moreover, I would like to know if it is possible to get an output (a unique dataframe) with the Pearson correlation coefficients and the associate significance levels?

Sorry for the question!

Comment: `cor()` will create a correlation matrix of your dataframe, `cor.prob()` will produce a matrix of the p-values

Answer (score 1):

`stats::cor.test` takes two inputs, `x` and `y`, which are numeric *vectors* of the same length -- see the documentation, `?cor.test` -- the long and short, you cannot feed `cor.test` a `data.frame`.

To get the desired behavior you are after you could use the `psych` package and its `corr.test()` function -- try the following:

```
# install.packages("psych")
library(psych)
corr.test(data1[sapply(data1, is.numeric)])
```

This will return the correlation matrix, the sample size, and a matrix of *p*-values. Per your example, you could use the following to extract just the *p*-values and assign them to `significance`:

```
significance <- corr.test(data1[sapply(data1, is.numeric)])$p
```

---

*N.B.* This will apply an adjustment factor to the returned *p*-values. Per the documentation for `psych::corr.test`:

*"For symmetric matrices, raw probabilites are reported below the diagonal and correlations adjusted for multiple comparisons above the diagonal. In the case of different x and ys, the default is to adjust the probabilities for multiple tests."*

You can turn off the *p*-value adjustment by using `adjust = "none"` like so...

`corr.test(data1[sapply(data1, is.numeric)], adjust = "none")`

...however, you should use caution when interpreting such results.
For more information on adjusted *p*-values, see `?p.adjust`.

Answer (score 1):

`cor.test` has a very specific input method. Let's say you have two variables in your data `x` and `y`:

```
cor.test(~ x + y, data)
```

will get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Without a reproducible example this is a bit onerous. I'll use the iris dataset for your example. The reason that your `cor.test()` call isn't working is because you need to specify which variables you'd like to compare. Look at `?cor.test` for more details.

But if you want to get at this issue with a dataframe I'd recommend the `dplyr` package. First you need to understand how to extract values from a `cor.test()` object. Run the correlation:

```
iris.cor <- cor.test(iris$Petal.Width, iris$Petal.Length)
```

Then look at the structure of the dataframe:

```
str(iris.cor)
```

Notice that you can extract values from the cor.test() object like this:

```
iris.cor$estimate
iris.cor$p.value
```

Now if you want to include these values in a dataframe there are several ways to do it. My preference would be a `dplyr` solution but there are many ways to skin this cat.

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
  summarise(coef=cor.test(Petal.Width, Petal.Length)$estimate,
            pval=cor.test(Petal.Width, Petal.Length)$p.value)
```

This has the advantage of adding other elements of the `cor.test()` object easily or adding a grouping variable:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(coef=cor.test(Petal.Width, Petal.Length)$estimate,
            pval=cor.test(Petal.Width, Petal.Length)$p.value)
```

At the end of the day R always several ways of doing things. Here is one.

Comment: this is pretty complicated for a simple question - no reason to introduce the dplyr package

Comment: @ Senor O How would you create the output that original question requested? If you read the original question, he didn't just want to run a correlation but also wanted to extract elements and combine them into a dataframe. I was pretty clear that there were other ways to do this.